# pass array of string to gettestdata

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database of data in two columns. i performed query by below on data base.It works well for a string word.How can i pass an array of words (words[i]) to gettestdata to perform query on database

```
 public Cursor getTestData(word) 
 { 
     try 
     { 


         String sql ="SELECT suggest_text_2 FROm FTSdictionary WHERE suggest_text_1='"+word+"'"; 

         Log.v("Query",sql );

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
         if (mCur!=null) 
         { 
            mCur.moveToNext(); 
         } 
         return mCur; 
     } 
     catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
         throw mSQLException; 
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sql query something like this :

```
String mQuery = "";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    mQuery.length() < 1 ? mQuery += "'" + words[i] + "'" : mQuery += ", '"+ words[i] + "'";
}
String sql ="SELECT suggest_text_2 FROm FTSdictionary WHERE suggest_text_1 in ('"+ mQuery +"')";
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Vipul. I am very new to java.Can you please tell me a simple way of writing a for loop over an array words[i]. and pass it accordingly.

Comment: @ Vipul. It says mQuery.length cannot be resolved to variable.